# Jquery Date picker is not showing in bootstrap model popup in asp.net

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

Jquery Date is not showing in popup model. Below is what i am doing.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="DateModel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Attachment</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <label class="col-sm-5 control-label" for="Description">Date</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-7">
                                                <div class="input-group date">
                                                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="datepicker">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger" type="button">OK</button>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

Below is my client side code

```
 $(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
         autoclose: true
         })
```

I don't know where i am doing wrong. It also raised the error **Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined**.

Answer (score 0):

you should add `;` and reference **jquery** libs like below.

```js
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    autoclose: true});
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="DateModel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title">Attachment</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <label class="col-sm-5 control-label" for="Description">Date</label>
                                            <div class="col-sm-7">
                                                <div class="input-group date">
                                                    <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="datepicker">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-danger" type="button">OK</button>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```